# undefined reference to mongo::curTimeMillis64()

Tags: c++, mongodb, build, linker

I have this sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mongo/util/time_support.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << mongo::curTimeMillis64() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and compile with:

```
g++ -I/tmp/include prova.cpp -o prova -L/tmp/lib -lmongoclient
```

the result is:

```
/tmp/ccH0vDvx.o: In function `main':
prova.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `mongo::curTimeMillis64()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I use the 26compat of mongo cxx driver and i have also check with nm the symbols within the library:

```
nm /tmp/lib/libmongoclient.so | grep curTime
00000000000ea510 t _ZN5mongo13curTimeMicrosEv
00000000000ea4f0 t _ZN5mongo15curTimeMicros64Ev
00000000000ea440 t _ZN5mongo15curTimeMillis64Ev
```

everything seems to be ok but the compile fails. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answer on the mongodb-user forum where you posted this same question: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/ZljQP66lJLg